# EasyMock on Spring jdbcTemplate is always returning null rather mocked object

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, easymock

I'm trying to use EasyMock 3.4 on a Java Spring project. I have successfully mocked all objects and tested the classes except a DAO which is using JDBCTemplate.

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class DummyDAOImplTest extends EasyMockSupport {

    @TestSubject
    private DummyDAOImpl dummyDAOImpl  = new DummyDAOImpl ();

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        jdbcTemplateObject = EasyMock.createNiceMock(JdbcTemplate.class);       
        dummyDAOImpl.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplateObject);
     }

    @Test
    public void testGetApplicationConfigValueReturnNonNull(){
        String query = "SELECT value FROM application_configuration WHERE tag=?";
        String tag = "REFRESH_INTERVAL";
        EasyMock.expect(jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(query,new Object[] {tag}, String.class)).andReturn("12");
        EasyMock.replay(jdbcTemplateObject);
        Assert.assertEquals(12,dummyDAOImpl.getApplicationConfigValue(tag));
    }
}

public class ConfigurationDAOImpl implements ConfigurationDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    @Override
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public int getApplicationConfigValue(String tag) {
        String query = "SELECT value FROM application_configuration WHERE tag=?";
        String refreshTime = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(query,new Object[] {tag}, String.class);
        if(refreshTime != null && !"".equals(refreshTime))
            return new Integer(refreshTime);
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Though in method *testGetApplicationConfigValueReturnNonNull* - I'm trying to mock it to return 12 but it always returns null.

It's the first time I'm using EasyMock. anything that I'm missing as already tried for and not able to crack it!

Best Regards,
Sundar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your only problem is your expectation line. It should be

```
EasyMock.expect(jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(eq(query), aryEq(new Object[] {tag}), eq(String.class))).andReturn("12");
```

By default, EasyMock will perform an `equals` on parameter to match the expectation. The things is that there are no `equals` defined for an array. So you need to specify a matcher for array (`aryEq`). And as soon as you have a matcher for an argument, you need to have one for all of them (for technical reasons).

The full code with some simplifications is below.

1. I assumed it is `ConfigurationDAO` that you want to test
2. You can `replayAll` since you are extending EasyMockSupport
3. You can use `@Mock` because of the runner
4. You do not need a nice mock. In fact, not using it here will have shown a nice exception about the unexpected call that would have been really helpful for you
5. The mock is now also injected by the `EasyMockRunner`
6. I prefer to add a `verifyAll` at the end of most of my tests. It makes sure that all expectations were used
7. Static imports because I think it's clearer to read

Code:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class DummyDAOImplTest extends EasyMockSupport {

  @TestSubject
  private ConfigurationDAOImpl dao = new ConfigurationDAOImpl();

  @Mock
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

  @Test
  public void testGetApplicationConfigValueReturnNonNull(){
    String query = "SELECT value FROM application_configuration WHERE tag=?";
    String tag = "REFRESH_INTERVAL";

    expect(jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(eq(query), aryEq(new Object[] {tag}), eq(String.class))).andReturn("12");

    replayAll();

    assertEquals(12, dao.getApplicationConfigValue(tag));

    verifyAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Henri - thanks a lot mate and that explains a lot where I was going wrong but still not able to get hold of why i need to do that.. Any document or reference to go through and learn more about this ? As i used same technique @Mock for service class and all worked expect for DAO classes.. Said that by doing similar change my jdbctemplate.update not working now :( not sure how to format the code here as I'm not use to post questions much..

Comment: @Test
  public void updateDashboardAppRefreshConfigurationTest() {
      
      String query = "UPDATE application_configuration SET value=? WHERE tag=?"; 
      Configuration config = new Configuration();
      config.setTag(ApplicationConstant.DASHBOARD_APP_REFRESH_INTERVAL.getValue());;
      config.setRefreshInterval(20);
      expect(jdbcTemplateObject.update(eq(query), aryEq(new Object[] { config.getRefreshInterval(),config.getTag() } ) )).andReturn(0);
      replayAll();
      assertEquals(0,configurationDAOImpl.updateConfiguration(config));
      verifyAll();
  }

Comment: The documentation is here http://easymock.org/user-guide.html. If something is missing, please tell me. I need the error to know what's wrong. And I don't think we can format in a comment. If you want to be more flexible on your parameters, you can use the `anyObject()` matcher.

Comment: @Henri, I'm getting error "Expectation failure on verify: .. expected 1, actual: 0 when I try to use eq(sql), aryEq(new Object[] {"123", "456"}), eq(new MyClass()) , could you provide suggestion on what the syntax would be to use any() matchers?

Comment: @WallaceHowery asking a question in a comment of a one-year-old question isn't a good idea. You should ask your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to load the Spring context

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context-test.xml")
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class) public class DummyDAOImplTest extends EasyMockSupport { ...
```

Override your appplication-context like this

application-context-test.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd"><import resource="application-context.xml"/><bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:your-db-conection" />
  <property name="username" value="" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
```

Comment: if i'm doing that its working even without mock objects as context has my database config. But i want to make my test-case independent of database. SO only went for mock objects where i can mock the return of data object instead of actual DB call.

Comment: Updated above..The idea is create a new test context that imports your original context and overrides your datasource. Hope it helps

Comment: Interesting.. I already have a separate test context. But is it not still dependent on DB..? I can see you mentioned HSQLDB.. you meant have internal temporary DB ? - Thanks for your reply and suggestions.. Appreciate it !!

Comment: HSQLDB it was an example i had. Take a look here http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/how-you-should-unit-test-dao-layer/

Comment: No, you don't need an application context. You are doing it right. See my answer.